# multiple subscriber multiple publisher

Tags: ros, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello I want to subscribe to rgb and depth image simultaneously and publish it to multiple topics using one node in cvbrige, plz guide me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64964/multiple-subscriber-multiple-publisher/) by [ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/5130/ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that this is a duplicate of [Synchronizer and image_transport::subscriber](http://answers.ros.org/question/9705/synchronizer-and-image_transportsubscriber/)

You can create a message filter that wraps around the two `image_transports` associated with the RGB and depth images.

You can then process these the way you normally would using OpenCV and `cv_bridge` and publish as normal.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1